# Are <input type="hidden"> tamper proof?

Tags: security, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Does Asp.Net Core prevent hidden inputs from being tampered? Is there signing of some sort handled by the middleware to prevent tampering? Does the `__RequestVerificationToken` take care of that?

Comment: As they say: never trust anything that comes from the client. I know many systems have things you can add to prevent client-side tampering, but, ehh...

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core implements antiforgery using [ASP.NET Core Data Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Antiforgery middleware is added to the Dependency injection container when one of the following APIs is called in `Startup.ConfigureServices`: AddMvc, MapRazorPages, MapControllerRoute and MapBlazorHub.

When we add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken` in the `<form>` element, it will generate the hidden field to store the antiforgery token.

`<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8NrAkS ... s2-m9Yw">`

The token is unique and unpredictable. The server sends the token associated with the current user's identity to the client. The client sends back the token to the server for verification. If the server receives a token that doesn't match the authenticated user's identity, the request is rejected.

More detail information, please checking the [Prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery (XSRF/CSRF) attacks in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: Does it detect for tampering to `<input type='hidden'>`s that I have in the form? For example, if I have `<input type='hidden' name='id' value='555'>` and the user presses F12 and changes the value before submitting, does the middleware detect this and reject?

Comment: @OldGeezer No it doesn't, and this answer is rather misleading, because it's subtly suggesting the opposite. Hidden fields are not protected from tampering.

Comment: Agree with Gabor Lengyel, it doesn't detect the hidden field.